# Basic external JavaScript to display date

Tags: javascript, date, hyperlink, external

I'm trying to test to see if my external JavaScript file is accessible. It is in the same directory as the web page that's calling it.  I have the following between the Head tags:

```
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

And this Span element is between the Body tags:

```
<span id="demo" onLoad="displayDate()"></span>
```

And finally, the contents of controller.js:

```
function displayDate() {
var date = new Date();
document.getElementByID("demo")innerHTML = date.toDateString();
}
```

What could I possibly be missing?

Comment: `onload` is not an attribute of the `span` element. Try doing `onload="displayDate()"` on the `body` tag instead.

Comment: And you're missing a dot after `getElementById("demo")`, before `innerHTML`

Comment: also, innerHTML is a bad idea generally. if you're just testing, thats ok, but if you're going to alter elements generally, check the `document` object on MDN or somewhere like that and use its methods instead to create and change elements.

Comment: Hanlet: So so simple! Thank you very much! I moved "onload" to the body tag for now but I see I might create a problem for myself down the road with how I'm trying to do this. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: IvyLynx: OK, I'll read up on that. It's my first time hearing of what you speak as all I see is innerHTML solutions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Try to replace it with this:

```
document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = date.toDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

`<span>` elements don't have `onload` event.

In order to call `displayDate` after loading `#demo` to the DOM, you can use

```
<span id="demo"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
displayDate()
</script>
```